# C++ simple file read-in to array question

Tags: c++, arrays, file, input

Simple quick question. 
Whats the best way to read in an array of float values that you don't know how long they will be?
(However we know it will not be longer than 75 integers long)

Lets say I have a file (derp.txt)
and the integers are 5.3 6.2 1.5 5.0 1.4 4.5.....etc

and I want to put them into array numbers[75];
Whats the best way of doing this in C++ (and if your feeling awesome C)

I was thinking it'd be a combination of stringstreams and getline, but im not familiar with stringstreams at all.

edit: i forgot to mention this.
After that array is another 2 numbers which dont belong into that array (they are easy to read in) so basically I just need to read till the end of the line

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
std::vector<double> results;
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<double>(std::cin),
          std::istream_iterator<double>(),
          std::back_inserter(results));
```

You can replace `std::cin` with whatever stream you are actually using.

It's a bit messier to read into an array, but you probably don't want to use an array anyway; you said that you don't know how long the list of values will be, so how do you know that 75 is the correct size for the array?  With `std::vector`, you don't have this problem.

Comment: To add to that answer: just use a ifstream instead of std::cin and you're good to go.

Comment: @Mercfh, it copies to the end of the stream, that and the end of the line may or may not be the same...

Comment: @Mercfh: It copies until the stream fails; the stream can fail because it reaches EOF or because an extraction error occurs (e.g. if the file contained "abcdef" somewhere). If you want to read only a single line from the file, consider reading the line into a `std::string` using `std::getline` and then using a `std::istringstream` to extract the contents from the line. Generally this two-step approach is preferable if you want to treat newlines specially so that you can ensure the data is formatted correctly.  I would also consult your C++ book's I/O chapter(s).

Comment: Ok...but lets say I have something AFTER that line that doesn't need to be read into the array. So like That array THEN another 2 numbers that dont belong. So I would need just to the end of that line, not to the end of file.

Comment: @Mercfh:  In that case you would need to know how many elements you need to copy out of the stream (you said you didn't know).  The easiest way to do that is to use `std::copy_n`; it's not part of the current C++ standard library but it is part of C++0x, recent compilers should include it, and it's easy and straightforward to write.

Comment: Isn't there some kind of read till end of LINE function? Like i'd read in the array till end of line. then just read in the 2 normal values after that? I do know how many values will be in the "line" however. I read in the first value (like 5) which tell's me there will be 5 values to go into that array

Comment: @Mercfh:  Yes, you can use `std::getline`, `std::istringstream`, and then `std::copy` the elements from the line you read.

Comment: myfile >> nCoeff;
   while (count < nCoeff){
   myfile >> coeff[count];
   count++;
   }
   myfile >> a >> b;    I thought something like this would work, since the first number will tell me the number of coefficients (the floats for the array), so then I read them in....until the counter gets too high. then I read in the next 2 numbers. but it seg faults. ARGGG

Comment: You can't read into an index of a vector that doesn't exist yet. You can resize the vector ahead of time (using the nCoeff value that you read), or you can use .push_back() to append to the end of the vector.